# I need to save and load data to a JSON file, and I already did it, but know I have a problem

Tags: python

I am using this to load the information from the file to the directory receipts.

```
receipts = {}

with open("receipts.json","r") as file_receipts:
    load_receipts = json.load(file_receipts)
    receipts = load_receipts
    file_receipts.close()
```

It works when I have the json file created, and it has information in it... But when the file is without information, the program crash, so How can I avoid the program to crash when the program is running for 1st time?

Also when the json file has information, it has something like this:

```
{"Josh": {"n_orders": 2, "id0": {"combo_1": {"dish": "Personal Pizza", "drink": "Soda", "order": "French Fries", "price": "8", "id": "combo"}}, "id1": {"soda": {"order": "Soda", "price": "2", "id": "order"}}}, "Mary": {"n_orders": 2, "id0": {"pizza": {"order": "Personal Pizza", "price": "4", "id": "dish"}}, "id1": {"soda": {"order": "Soda", "price": "2", "id": "order"}}}}
```

Comment: Before loading, you can determine whether the file needs to be loaded or not. For example, if the file byte is 0 or does not exist, it will not be loaded.

Comment: can you edit your question to include the stacktrace that is displayed? You probably just need to wrap the json loading in a try block

Comment: How does it crash? Is the file not found? Is the file empty? It seems like you expect the file to have a dict. Does it have a default, required structure?

Comment: side note the `file_receipts.close()` is redundant and unecessary. The nice thing about the `with` is that it will close `file_receipts` at the end of th eblock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Catch the `FileNotFoundError` exception, like this:

```
try:
    with open("receipts.json","r") as file_receipts:
        receipts = json.load(file_receipts)
except FileNotFoundError:
    receipts = {}
    print("File doesn't exist yet.")
```

And I've simplified your code a little bit, you don't need to close files that are opened using `with`, because they'll be closed automatically when execution leaves the `with` block.

Answer (score 1):

use try except:

```
import os

receipts = {}

if os.path.exist("receipts.json"):
    with open("receipts.json","r") as file_receipts:
        try:
           load_receipts = json.load(file_receipts)
           receipts = load_receipts
        except:
           pass # error handling
        # file_receipts.close() # this is not needed inside "with"
```